# Running multiple pox controllers

Tags: python, sdn, pox

I have created a topology in mininet(as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3wej.png)). I want to run 2 pox controllers.Calculate the load on controller c0 and migrate to controller c1.
Currently I am running pox controller as:

**from terminal 1**

```
cd pox
./pox.py openflow.of_01 --port=6633
```

and 
**from terminal 2**

```
cd pox
./pox.py openflow.of_01 --port=6634
```

and 
mininet custom topology as

```
sudo  python  ~/mininet/custom/customtopo.py
```

**Result:**

No ping request is satisfied.

What is proper way to run two controllers?

Comment: Try again but add to each controller a stock component ie. forwarding.l2_pairs

Answer (score 1):

In order to run two controllers we do following
On terminal 1

```
./pox.py forwarding.l2_pairs openflow.of_01 --port=6633
```

On terminal 2

```
./pox.py forwarding.l2_pairs openflow.of_01 --port=6634
```

On terminal 3 we run the mininet

```
sudo  python  ~/mininet/custom/customtopo.py
```

using forwarding.l2_pairs enables OpenFlow switches act like a type of L2 learning switch.  However, this one is probably just about the simplest possible way to do it correctly.  Unlike l2_learning, l2_pairs installs rules based purely on MAC addresses.
Reference:[here](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-ComponentsinPOX)